# Angular2 How to bind a route parameter to a variable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem trying to bind the id of a route parameter to a variable.

The following error appears on the console:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 15 in [['/envio',{id:'{{text}}'}]] in AppComponent@3:11 ("
        <h1>Angular 2 Boilerplate</h1>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/envio',{id:'{{text}}'}]">Go</a>
    "): AppComponent@3:11
```

**The component that throws the exception:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, RouterLink} from "angular2/router";
import {EnvioIDComponent} from "./id.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2 Boilerplate</h1>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <a [routerLink]="['/envio',{id:'{{text}}'}]">Go</a>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]    
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/home', name: 'Inicio', component: AppComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/envio/:id', name: 'EnvioID', component: EnvioIDComponent},

])

export class AppComponent {

    text:string='fine';
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the variable directly:

---

`<a [routerLink]="['EnvioID',{id:text'}]">Go</a>`

A problem in your code is, you should use route name instead route path in `routerLink`.

Answer (score 0):

I made several changes in my code, including your solution Jiang YD, and now the following error appears:

```
Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(RouteRegistry, Router, ?, Router).
```

Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Router' is decorated with Injectable.

The files of the project are:

**boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router} from "angular2/router";

bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,Router]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, RouterLink, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {EnvioIDComponent} from "./id.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2 Boilerplate</h1>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <a [routerLink]="['EnvioID',{id:text}]">Go</a>
    `,
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]  
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/envio/:id', name: 'EnvioID', component: EnvioIDComponent}
])

export class AppComponent {

    text:string='fine';
}
```

**id.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, RouteConfig, RouterLink, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'envio',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2 Boilerplate</h1>
        <p>{{titulo}}{{id}}</p>
        <a [routerLink]="['Inicio']">Go back</a>
    `,
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Inicio', component: AppComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])

export class EnvioIDComponent {

    titulo:string='Success';
    id:string;

    constructor(private _params:RouteParams)
    {
        this.id=_params.get('id');
    }
}
```

Comment: seems your project not configured well,  i can not run the `plnkr` project you post. please use official example as base `https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html`

Comment: I already compared my project to that sample and made several changes, but a lot of errors still showing up...I don't know what I'm doing wrong. plnkr.co/edit/ImicQGUYXtqgtggSOMyN?p=preview

Comment: I fixed most of these errors but now the link of the children page (Go back) doesn't work http://plnkr.co/edit/IifRRkNEJJfMKc4GHtMi?p=previewplnkr.co/edit/ImicQGUYXtqgtggSOMyN?p=preview

Comment: so `bind a route parameter to a variable` is solved right? please edit your question or ask another one.

Comment: Yes, the main question is already solved. I will ask a new one for that issue.Thanks for everything!